# Can't access class variables besides from in SwiftIU view

Tags: swift

So I'm trying to access my data by id using a url such as `http://localhost:8000/albums/whateverid`.

**First I gain the ids**

```
class Webservice {
    func getAllPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/albums")
     else {
     fatalError("URL is not correct!")
    }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            let posts = try!

                JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!); DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(posts)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

```
struct Post: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {

    let id: String
    let title: String
    let path: String
    let description: String
}
```

**Set the variables to the data from `class Webservice`**

```
final class PostListViewModel: ObservableObject {

    init() {
        fetchPosts()
    }

    @Published var posts = [Post]()


    private func fetchPosts() {
        Webservice().getAllPosts {
            self.posts = $0
            print("posts \(self.posts)")
        }
    }

}
```

---

**And this is how I'm trying to grab album by id by using the id I fetched from the code above**

**I create a class that when a id is inserted will give me the album data back by id**

```
class SecondWebService: Identifiable {
    var id:String = ""

    init(id: String?) {
        self.id = id!
        }

    func getAllPostsById(completion: @escaping ([PostById]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/albums/\(id)")
     else {
     fatalError("URL is not correct!")
    }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            let posts = try!

                JSONDecoder().decode([PostById].self, from: data!); DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(posts)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Variables**

```
struct PostById: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String?
    let path: String
}
```

**Here's where I try to insert the `id` from `class PostListViewModel` into my `class SecondWebService` to get the data back set my variables to that data**

```
final class PostListViewByIdModel: ObservableObject {

    @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()

    init() {
       fetchPostsById()
     }

    @Published var postsById = [PostById]()

    private func fetchPostsById() {
        for post in model.posts {
           SecondWebService(id: post.id).getAllPostsById {
           self.postsById = $0
           print("postById \(post)")

        }

  }

 }

}
```

For some reason above when I try to print nothing will display because I believe posts in model.posts isn't getting read

When I use it here in List() it works but not in init:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()

    init() {
        for post in model.posts {
            print(post)
    }
}

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
            List(model.posts) { post in

                 VStack{

                        Text("Title: ").bold()
                          + Text("\(post.title)")
                        NavigationLink(destination: Album(post: post)) {
                        ImageView(withURL: "http://localhost:8000/\(post.path.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))")
                        }
                        Text("Description: ").bold()
                        + Text("\(post.description)")

                }
            }

    }

}

}
```

I'm very curious on why nothing is printing when I use model.posts in my for loop. Only when I use it in the SwiftUI functions does it work.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm very curious on why nothing is printing when I use model.posts in my for loop

It is because of asynchronous nature of the following call

```
private func fetchPosts() {
    Webservice().getAllPosts {
```

so in `init`

```
  @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel() // just created

    init() {

        for post in model.posts {  // posts are empty because 
                                   // `Webservice().getAllPosts` has not finished yet
            print(post)
    }
```

**Update:** You need to call second service after first one got finished, here is possible approach (only idea - cannot test)

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()
  @ObservedObject var model2 = PostListViewByIdModel()

  // delete init() - it is not needed here

  ...
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(model.posts) { post in
           ...
        }
        .onReceive(model.$posts) { posts in // << first got finished
            self.model2.fetchPostsById(for: posts)    // << start second
        }
        .onReceive(model2.$postsById) { postById in
           // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

and updated second service

```
final class PostListViewByIdModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var postsById = [PostById]()

    func fetchPostsById(for posts: [Post]) { // not private now
        for post in model.posts {
           SecondWebService(id: post.id).getAllPostsById {
           self.postsById = $0
           print("postById \(post)")

        }
  }
```

Comment: So what's your solution sir?

Comment: Solution for what? I see only one question in post. And you wrote in body it shown well... so what's the problem?

Comment: On this line is where I'm trying to use model.posts `SecondWebService(id: post.id).getAllPostsById {
           self.postsById = $0
           print("postById \(post)")
 }
`
But it's not working because like you said `Webservice().getAllPosts` probably hasn't finished yet

Comment: I'm using this in another SwiftUI View but it does work. What am I supposed to do with the data though. How can I use the data in my SwiftUI View?